# Jquery Ajax Dynamic fields auto complete and auto fill

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, jquery-autocomplete, autofill

I'm trying  to do jquery autocomplete and autofill for dynamic form field.
Here i'm done with autocomplete for dynamic form fields.But the auto fill is working for only one field.Here the fields 'Name' and 'Price'.The field 'Name' is auto complete and in onkey down the price of the particular product is autofilled.But auto fill is not working for dynamic fields.If any thing please suggest me guys.It will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.
Here is my code

```
{% load jsonify %}
<!doctype html>
  <script src="/static/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/jquery-ui.css">
<form method="post" action="/add/">{% csrf_token %}
    <label>Category</label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="category">
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="+" />
    <div id="myTabContent" class="input_fields_wrap">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
//dynamic form and autocomplete
  $(function () {
    var availableTags = {{ material_list|jsonify }};
    console.log(availableTags)
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        if (i <= 100)
                i++;  
        $('#myTabContent').append(
            '<div>Name:<input name="name_'+i+'" type="text" id="field" class="searchInput" placeholder="Name" onkeydown="myMaterial()" />Price<input type="text" name="price_'+i+'" id="price" placeholder="Price"><input type="button" id="btn" value="-" class="remove_field" /></div>');
        $(".searchInput").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
});

//autofill
function myMaterial(){
    var searchInput = document.getElementById("field").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/material/list/entry/',
        data : {
            name : searchInput,
        },        
        success: function (response) {
            price.value = response['price'];

        },        
    });
  }  
//Remove field
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); i--;
})


</script>
```